# Inserting a data into SQLite (using FMDB) doesn't work on device?

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite, fmdb

I am a newbie here. I am not able to insert any data into my SQLite database when running on my device. I am using the below piece of code to connect SQLite. It works perfect in my simulator but doesn't work on my iPad device. Can anyone help please? Thank you.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DADatabase1.sqlite"];
NSLog(@"%@", writableDBPath);

FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];

/*if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath] == NO) {
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DADatabase1.sqlite" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:writableDBPath error:nil];
}*/
[db open];
[db traceExecution];
[db beginTransaction];
BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into PatientDetails (patAge) values (?)",patAge.text]];
if(!success)
{
    NSLog(@"Query not success!");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Query success!");
}
//NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:];
[db commit];
[db close];
```

Comment: you also have to replace ? by %@ because ? is for prepared Statements

Comment: Okay but it does work perfectly on the simulator. So, do you think this causes the problem? Thanks

Comment: your Patient Age should be '?' in your database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put your `Database` with your `Tables` in your Projects resources folder? You have to copy your database file to your `Apps Document` folder.

```
+ (BOOL)initDB {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sqlite.db"]; 

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    NSString *bundle =  [[ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sqlite" ofType:@"db"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:nil];
    return YES;
}
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: 100
2012-08-06 13:10:31.806 Pro_sample[317:707] Anesthesia, Local
2012-08-06 13:10:36.751 Pro_sample[317:707] Count of Sample Array: 1
2012-08-06 13:10:36.758 Pro_sample[317:707] /var/mobile/Applications/453590BF-DCA9-4768-BDBA-75E1087E6CE8/Documents/DADatabase1.sqlite
2012-08-06 13:10:36.765 Pro_sample[317:707] Query not success!

Comment: I added the database file manually into the Documents folder. Do I have to do anything programmatically?

Comment: Yes you have to do it programmatically with my Code, because Files from your Simulator Document Folder will no be copied to your Device

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DADatabase1.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSLog(@"%@", writableDBPath);

Comment: if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath])
    {
        NSString *bundle =  [[ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DADatabase1" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        NSLog(@"%@", bundle);
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:writableDBPath error:nil];
    }

Comment: I have added the above code in my project and set a breakpoint at the if statement. It doesn't go inside the if statement. So, that means the database file is inside the documents folder. Correct? Console NSLog shows: <p> /var/mobile/Applications/453590BF-DCA9-4768-BDBA-75E1087E6CE8/Documents/DADatabase1.sqlite

Comment: Same behavior on an iOS Device?

Comment: Well, it doesn't care about the if statement. No matter whether it is on device or simulator. When running on simulator, this is what NSLog shows:/Users/raghuvardhan/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/91B32953-7C6A-4C0C-8099-C19BCAC71991/Documents/DADatabase1.sqlite
2012-08-06 15:57:40.947 Pro_sample[1755:f803] Query success!

Comment: When running on iPad device, this is what I get: /var/mobile/Applications/453590BF-DCA9-4768-BDBA-75E1087E6CE8/Documents/DADatabase1.sqlite
2012-08-06 15:59:54.449 Pro_sample[763:707] Query not success!

Comment: Seems strange! Hard time here with this.. :( I really appreciate your help. Thanks BTW

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",[db lastErrorMessage]);
Whats the Error Message?

Comment: 2012-08-06 16:05:35.218 Pro_sample[811:707] Database Path: /var/mobile/Applications/453590BF-DCA9-4768-BDBA-75E1087E6CE8/Documents/DADatabase1.sqlite
2012-08-06 16:05:35.222 Pro_sample[811:707] **bold** Error: out of memory

Comment: lastErrorMessage says "Out of memory".. Puzzling??

Comment: Remove: [db open];
[db traceExecution];
[db beginTransaction];
[db commit];
Add:

db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
        db.traceExecution = YES;
        db.logsErrors = YES;
        [db open];

Comment: Did so... Here is what Log screen shows:        2012-08-06 16:14:42.298 Pro_sample[849:707] <FMDatabase: 0x1e0460> executeUpdate: insert into PatientDetails (patAge) values ('78')
2012-08-06 16:14:42.302 Pro_sample[849:707] DB Error: 1 "no such table: PatientDetails"
2012-08-06 16:14:42.307 Pro_sample[849:707] DB Query: insert into PatientDetails (patAge) values ('78')
2012-08-06 16:14:42.311 Pro_sample[849:707] DB Path: /var/mobile/Applications/453590BF-DCA9-4768-BDBA-75E1087E6CE8/Documents/DADatabase1.sqlite

Comment: Worked perfectly after copying the DB file into Documents folder. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The sample code provided doesn't have a `CREATE TABLE` statement. The `INSERT` has nowhere to insert to. Did you create the table manually (using the `sqlite3` command line tool) while you were developing in the simulator?

Comment: I in-fact created the table using SQLite Manager (Firefox add-on). It just works fine in the simulator. I can't get why it doesn't do anything when on device. Am I missing anything in terms of database file path specification?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Firefox plug ing, but presumably there were some steps in which you specified that a PatientDetails table should exist and which columns it should have? Looking at your code, the database is expected to be in the Documents folder, which is fine and correct. But that folder and its contents aren't (to my understanding) copied across to the real device. Your code needs to create the table for itself. To avoid the need to check for first run, you can just use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...` and the right thing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE** that:

File names in simulator is not case sensitive, but in device is case sensitive. Make sure your file name is exactly same.